# Facing an issue with using camera by intent in Android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want to take a picture and store it in a folder with the name Medit via my app. When my app starts, it should be able to pull all the pictures from this folder and display it directly. So the data storage path must be set and stored as part of the app. Here is what I have done so far

```
 public void CaptureImage(){
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        mediaStorageDir =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyAppName");
        mUri =Uri.fromFile(mediaStorageDir+"IMG"+System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mUri.getPath());
            imgVIew.setImageBitmap(bm);
           }else Log.d("capture", "FAILED");}
```

Issue is, irrespective what i change mUri to the picture is being stored in DCIM/ camera images with the default naming convention. In the onActivityResult I am capturing the image. Issue is Im not able to comtrol where it is being stored and as what name. I need to

1) Capture an image via intent, store it in a location with a custom name.

2) Everytime the app opens, it should go to that same storage location and pull out the pictures and display them one by one.

Comment: please paste your onActivityResult

Comment: just did. I need a path to access. I was using http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/ as reference but this app for some reason is crashing on my friend's phone nonstop. All phones may not have an external SD card so I need to check for that as well?

Comment: there is no secure path, because the user can see the most recent changes to the SdCard or Internal Storages. So you have to Encrypt your data if they are sensitive

Comment: No data isnt secure. My bad. I just mean a path that I can keep reusing since I want to load same pictures once the app starts.

Comment: Look up Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: I am already using that in my code. I use a toast to display the storage location and name which is coming to be fine. But the picture is saved else where under different name!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88996/discussion-between-hoseinit-and-varun-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

> irrespective what i change mUri to the picture is being stored in DCIM/ camera images with the default naming convention

Most likely, that is a bug in that camera app. Most camera apps will honor `EXTRA_OUTPUT` properly. However, there is no enforcement mechanism to ensure that a camera app will honor `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

However, please do not use string concatenation to create a file path, and make sure that you create your directories. IOW, replace:

```
mediaStorageDir =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyAppName");
mUri =Uri.fromFile(mediaStorageDir+"IMG"+System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
```

with:

```
mediaStorageDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyAppName");
mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
mUri=Uri.fromFile(new File(mediaStorageDir, "IMG"+System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
```

It is possible that changing this code will make your app more compatible with this particular camera app, but there are no guarantees that *all* camera apps will behave as you wish.

> I need to...

Your code is written to give you what you want. However, you are invoking a third-party app with the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`. There are thousands of camera apps, both pre-installed and available for download from the Play Store and elsewhere. Many will have properly-working `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementations. Some will not.

Either:

- Detect that the image is not at your desired path and let the user know that their camera app is broken. Then, suggest that they install some third-party camera app that you have tested. Or,
- Stop using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and work with the camera APIs directly, though this is rather difficult.

Comment: I replaced the needed lines as you said but it isnt changing where the image is being stored. it is still going to DCIM / Camera. I will get my friend's phone and try it on his.

Answer (score 0):

Your pictures are being save in default path because the path you are providing is wrong. Use the following code.

```
File mediaStorageDir =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyAppName");

    if(!mediaStorageDir.exists())
        mediaStorageDir.mkdir();

    Uri mUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/IMG" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
    LogHelper.LogI("path", mUri.getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try th following code it's working for me.

```
public class CaptureImage extends Activity {

private static final int PICK_CAMERA_IMAGE = 2;

ImageView img;
Button btn;

private Uri mImageCaptureUri;

public static String userPicPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_image);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_capture_image_img);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/" + Constants.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "img_"
                    + dateFormatter.format(new Date()).toString() + ".png");
            userPicPath = file.getPath();
            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CAMERA_IMAGE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_CAMERA_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Log.d("CaptureImage", mImageCaptureUri.toString());

        Bitmap bitmapProfile = getBitmap(userPicPath, this);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmapProfile);

    }
}

public static Bitmap getBitmap(String path, Context context) {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    InputStream in = null;
    ContentResolver mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    try {
        // final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 2048;
        final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1024;
        in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
        in.close();

        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int) Math.pow(
                    2,
                    (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                            / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth))
                            / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o2);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, stream);
        in.close();

        return b;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("CaptureImage", "file " + path + " not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("CaptureImage", "file " + path + " not found");
    }
    return null;
}
```

}